# Android google map marker/label similar to latest traffic map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am quite new to using google map on android. So far I found the following code snippet.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

This does a simple labelling of the marker. What I am looking is something like the picture below.What I want to do is how to show the label or inforwindow like its shows the traffic jam how minutes +8 min etc. I am not too sure is it to be done a label, custom info window or how?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Make sure your current location is detected in Google Map

### 2.Make sure your Google Map has traffic data available for your current location.

### 2.Make sure your Internet Connection is available for your Devices.

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);// Traffic line is on in mapview
       
    }
```