# Android textview border covering a big area of the map at the top

Tags: android, layout, textview

[image]I have the following layout. What I need is a textbox at left hand corner which later I will plug in a counter to show the map is going to refresh after certain seconds.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="com.example.ns.appversion1.MapActivityFragment1"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="96dip"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:background="@drawable/border"
                android:text="Refreshing 1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the border.xml. The problem now I just want the border to around the word but here it border the whole top area. I want to limit just within the words.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#0288D1" />
</shape>
```

Comment: "I just want the border to around the word" means what? you are applying it for the textView not for the word

Comment: I want for the word. But I when I apply it gets to whole of the text view and it looks ugly

Comment: warp the view then or post an expected output

Comment: I dont get you what you mean by warp the view?

Comment: can you attach a picture of what you have and what you want to achieve? tha way people can help you better

Comment: @user5313398 you have given a weight for your textView so anyway your background will apply to that by using wrap_content you can adjust view bounds of your tv

Comment: I have added an image to clarify my problem. If you see the blue box is covering the whole top.

Comment: @user5313398 check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TextView `layout_width="match_parent"` will take the full width that it can take and you are applying background to the view not for the text inside it so what you are saying is right.

Warp your view if you want to apply background only around the text

```
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="Refreshing 1"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Refer : [What's the difference between fill_parent and wrap_content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432763/whats-the-difference-between-fill-parent-and-wrap-content)

For your second question :

```
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#1bd4f6" /> <-- here
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#0288D1" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: @charus how if I want the background of the textview to be say white or some other color and have the border around it?

Comment: @Charus currently I am using shape so what changes must I make so that the background is not transparent but a specific color?

Comment: @charus you solution is ok but there is one issue below the Refreshing 1 text there is quite a big space before the box is bordered

Comment: @user5313398 updated the answer hope you will accept it ;)

Comment: @charus I saw got two item mind explain what these are different ?

Comment: @user5313398  just simplified it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135502/discussion-between-user5313398-and-charu).

Comment: @charus there is big space below the words before the box is close?

Comment: @user5313398 can you show that ? btw i am not charus  Hahaha :D its Charuක

Comment: any idea on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179894/android-google-map-marker-label-similar-to-latest-traffic-map